# Wrong output for base64 encoding

Tags: php, base64, sha1

Below is a string which I want to encode:

```
kiQfEEe89PM07508441110100MYR
```

I had just encoded the above string from some website and got the below output:

> **hex**: b22562fd60cc1bb65caedbaba6d28f21e47b66bb
>   **HEX**: B22562FD60CC1BB65CAEDBABA6D28F21E47B66BB
>   **h:e:x**: b2:25:62:fd:60:cc:1b:b6:5c:ae:db:ab:a6:d2:8f:21:e4:7b:66:bb
>   **base64**: siVi/WDMG7ZcrturptKPIeR7Zrs=

I want the above results using a PHP function. I can get accurate results for hex and HEX, but I am not able to get same result as base64.

I have tried the below code:

```
<?php
    echo sha1("kiQfEEe89PM07508441110100MYR");
?>
```

output : `b22562fd60cc1bb65caedbaba6d28f21e47b66bb`

```
<?php
    base64_encode("kiQfEEe89PM07508441110100MYR")
?>
```

output : `a2lRZkVFZTg5UE0wNzUwODQ0MTExMDEwME1ZUg==`   (This is incorrect)

I want to input `kiQfEEe89PM07508441110100MYR` and see the output as `siVi/WDMG7ZcrturptKPIeR7Zrs=` using a PHP function.

Comment: You should be more specific about ***en**coding* and ***de**coding*. Show some code attempts, and clearly define input and *expected* output.

Comment: please check add more description

Comment: You can't reverse a sha1() because it's a hash; but if `base64_encode("kiQfEEe89PM07508441110100MYR");` gives `a2lRZkVFZTg5UE0wNzUwODQ0MTExMDEwME1ZUg==` then `base64_decode('a2lRZkVFZTg5UE0wNzUwODQ0MTExMDEwME1ZUg==');` will give `kiQfEEe89PM07508441110100MYR`

Answer (score 0):

The website wasn't giving you the base64 of that string, it was giving you the base64 of the binary output of the **SHA-1 hash** of that string (as you can tell because the "hex" output from the site matches the output you got from the SHA-1 hash). To replicate that in PHP, do:

```
echo base64_encode(sha1("kiQfEEe89PM07508441110100MYR", true));
```